# Como duplicar um triangulo randomicamente dentro do canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Estou tentando duplicar um triangulo aleatoriamente dentro do canvas quando pressiona alguma tecla, tipo, barra de espaço ou outra qualquer. Mas não sei como fazer para duplicar, se tenho que usar algum tipo de `constructor/array`.

Ate o momento so tenho o canvas e o triangulo:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Canvas</title>
   <script src="canvas.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
</head>
<body onload="setUp()">
    <h1>Triangle</h1>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" height="500" width="500" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>

    <br>
    <button type="button" id="resetbtt" name="button">Reset</button>

</body>

</html>
```

**JS:**

```
let canvas;
let ctx;
let dx = 10;
let dy = 10;
let x = 250;
let y = 250;
let WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500;


function setUp(){
   canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
   ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
   let resetbtt = document.getElementById('resetbtt');
   drawTriangle();
}

function drawTriangle(){

    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(x,y)
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(-15, 15);
    ctx.lineTo(15, 15);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let canvas;
let ctx;
let dx = 10;
let dy = 10;
let WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500;


function setUp(){
   canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
   ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
   let resetbtt = document.getElementById('resetbtt');

   document.body.onkeydown = function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 32){
            var x = randomInt(0,500);
            var y = randomInt(0,500);
            drawTriangle(x, y);
        }
    }
}

function drawTriangle(x, y) {

    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(x, y)
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(-15, 15);
    ctx.lineTo(15, 15);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();

}

function randomInt(min, max) { 
    return Math.floor(min + (Math.random() * ((max + 1) - min))); 
}
```

Comment: Tomás, não está funcionando. O triângulo não está reaparecendo randomicamente qdo aperta a barra de espaço

Comment: a barra de espaço às vezes cria conflitos